# how to modify virtualhost in WHM?

Tags: virtualhost, ruby-on-rails, whm

I generally manage my Linux servers by logging in as root and doing everything from the command line (because I just do small stuff) but I've been asked to take over a WHM/CPanel Service with multiple accounts and I need to get them moved onto SSL. For the most part I've managed this with the Wordpress sites but I have a Ruby on Rails site running, with an auto SSL installed but when going to `https://example.com` it gives a list of the files/directories. Where in WHM can I amend the virtual host so it directs the server correctly?

I have tried following [this link](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Modify+Apache+Virtual+Hosts+with+Include+Files) but including the conf files in `/usr/local/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/user/domain/includename.conf` because the CENTOS setup doesn't have a `/etc/apache2/` but it doesn't work.

I wondered if you could give some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Cpanel/WHM does NOT support Ruby on Rails out the box, you need to provision the `Ruby via mod_passenger` profile under your EasyApache 4 and deploy each application from Cpanel Application Manager Interface.

Sources

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Ruby+on+Rails

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Ruby+Installations